# Python character encoding with dnd data.get_text()

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pygtk

I want to get the name of the dropped file using gtk drag&drop. This is the code:

```
[...]
    self.scrolledwindow_play.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], Gdk.DragAction.COPY)
    self.scrolledwindow_play.connect('drag_data_received', self.on_drag_data_received_to_play)
    self.scrolledwindow_play.drag_dest_set_target_list(None)
    self.scrolledwindow_play.drag_dest_add_text_targets()

def on_drag_data_received_to_play(self, widget, drag_context, x,y, data,info, time):
    print data.get_text()
```

When i drag file and drop onto the widget, i take:

`file:///home/mnrl/Masa%C3%BCst%C3%BC/spinbutton.py` like this. But real file path is:

```
file:///home/mnrl/Masaüstü/spinbutton.py
```

Why is coding characters different? How can i take file path properly?

Answer (score 0):

Define your coding in the head of your python file like this :

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Be sure your editor is also set to the same encoding.